# How to read/write to sectors on certain LBA of a ISO File programmatically?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, native, sector

I would like to use C++ or other native programming language to read/write to sectors on a ISO using Logical Block Addressing (LBA). For example I want to read custom LBA of ISO file. Is this possible and if so how can I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible.

The question is how much effort you'll want to spend on it. You'd have to take a look at the specs for ISO files, and just read whatever you want to read from the file. There is no magic C++ feature that gives you access to ISO files in a more comfortable way.

However, just because there's no magic C++ feature doesn't mean that there can't be a third party library somewhere out there, in the vast reaches of the internet. For example, http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/ might be something to take a look at.